# SQL query for product information where only one customer bought this product before

Tags: mysql

I am studying RDMS in university and am currently working on a project of online shop database design. I got a question about writing a query for product information where only one customer bought this product before. I have a problem of dealing with the situation that one customer bought a single item many times.[What I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZFfM.png)

The query I wrote is

```
SELECT orders.customerID,orderdetails.ProductID,Count(*) 
FROM orders,orderdetails 
WHERE orders.transactionID = orderdetails.transactionID 
GROUP BY orders.customerID,orderdetails.ProductID
```

The correct answer from my table should be `ProductID 3,4,7,8,9.`

My question may not be clear enough, but I really need some help here and I have been stuck in thinking this for hours. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please embed your screenshot rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT d.ProductID
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderdetails d
  ON o.transactionID = d.transactionID 
GROUP BY d.ProductID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.customerID) = 1
```